# Munkres chapter 15 Lemma 15.1

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

in Lemma 15.1 Munkre shows:

*Let $ K'$ be a subdivision of the complex $ K $. For each vertex $ w\in K'$ there is a vertex $ v\in K $, such that $ St (w, K')\subseteq St (v, K) $.*

*If $\sigma $ is a simplex in $ K $, such that $ w\in Int\sigma $, then the inclusion holds, iff $ v $ is a vertex of $\sigma $.*

In the proof it is claimed that it suffices to show $|K|\setminus St (v, K)\subseteq |K| \setminus St (w, K') $ in order to prove the $\Leftarrow $ direction. Why does it suffices to show this?

The whole other part of the proof is clear.